# how can i access the elements of array which is located in a value of associative array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array which holds the data returned from an sql query

```
$user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$user["username"] = "username1";
$user["password"] = "password1";
```

I have also an associative array where `$user` array is saved as a value of a key:

```
return array("invalid credentials:"=>"false", "credentials"=>$user);
```

My question is how can I access the `values($user)` of `"credentials"` key 
I have tried `$user["credentials"] => "username";` but this obviously does not work

Comment: Check the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the value of a multidimentional array by stacking the keys in brackets;

So if your function returned the array you've created to `$arr`

```
$arr = somefunction(); // whatever the function you're calling is named
$username = $arr['credentials']['username'];
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea of how to achieve it

```
$functionReturn = array("invalid credentials:"=>"false", "credentials"=>$user);

$user = $functionReturn['credentials'];
var_dump($user["username"],$user["password"]);
```

or alternatively just:

```
$functionReturn['credentials']["username"];
$functionReturn['credentials']["password"];
```